# How do I know which version of MPICH I am having on my windows machine

Tags: mpi, mpich

I just wanted to check what is the version of the library I am having on my windows 7 machine. 
How do I do?

I have successfully run some some simple examples such as calculation of PI etc.

This I did by typing commands on CMD prompt.  I guess some command must exist for finding version.

Also the following does not work on my windows machine

> [mpiexec --version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356765/how-do-i-check-the-version-of-mpich)

```
C:\Users\acme>mpiexec --version 
Unknown option: -version Error: no executable specified Unable to parse the mpiexec command arguments.
```

Comment: have you tried `-version` or `/v`? Or just `mpiexec` and see what it says? Windows sometimes uses a slightly different syntax for arguments than the Unix world.

Comment: treid all possible combinations, but did not work:

Answer (score 0):

MPICH is is distributed with another binary in the bin/ directory called `mpichversion`. I'm assuming this is true in the old Windows distributions as well. (Windows hasn't been supported since 1.4.1p) If that's in there, you can just run that.